# What is the best way catch an error in the middle of a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have an Angular checkout validation process that has to pass certain async requests which send form information before allowing users to checkout.

I currently have all of the `$.ajax` calls firing on a `.then()` basis after the initial `$.ajax` function call. However, I am having an issue with catching an error in the middle of the promise chain.

In the code below, on the second promise call of `.then($scope.sendShippingInformation)` this is where I need to handle the error.

You see, the response gives me back a key value pair of `response.extensionAttributes.errorMessage : 'error message here';` If there is an error on the form. I need to be able to alert said error to the user, and allow them to correct whatever form field they didn't enter correctly. Allow them to fix it, and process the information again.

I have tried adding the `success: someFunctionHere` as well as the `error: someFunctionHere` to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Initial $.ajax request
$scope.sendPaymentInformation = function() {
  console.log('Send Billing Info');
  var guestUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/magento/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/billing-address/';
  var loggedInUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/magento/V1/carts/mine/billing-address/';
  var request = (KANE.isLoggedIn ? loggedInUrl : guestUrl);
  return $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: request,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        'address': {
          'region_code': 'TX',
          'country_id': KANE.territory,
          'street': ['1200 Lakeside Pkwy'],
          'postcode': $scope.creditCardZip,
          'city': 'Flower Mound',
          'firstname': 'Suraj',
          'lastname': 'Kolluri',
          'saveInAddressBook': 0,
          'telephone': $scope.phoneNumber,
          'email': $('#checkout-email').val(),
        }
      }),
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json"
    }).then($scope.sendShippingInformation)
    .then($scope.sendPaymentType)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}

// Second Request where I need to handle the error 
$scope.sendShippingInformation = function() {
  console.log('Send Shipping Information');
  var guestUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/magento/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/shipping-information/';
  var loggedInUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/magento/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information/';
  var request = (KANE.isLoggedIn ? loggedInUrl : guestUrl);
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: request,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'addressInformation': {
        'shippingAddress': {
          'region_code': $scope.state,
          'country_id': KANE.territory,
          'street': [$scope.streetAddress1],
          'postcode': $scope.zip,
          'city': $scope.city,
          'firstname': $scope.firstName,
          'lastname': $scope.lastName,
          'email': $scope.email,
          'telephone': $scope.phoneNumber,
        },
        'shippingMethodCode': templateShippingMethods[$scope.shippingMethod].method_code,
        'shippingCarrierCode': templateShippingMethods[$scope.shippingMethod].id
      }
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
  })
}

// Determine Payment Type
$scope.sendPaymentType = function() {
  if ($('#paypal').is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Checking Out With PayPal");
    var guestUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/paypal/checkout/';
    var loggedInUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/paypal/checkout/';
    var request = (KANE.isLoggedIn ? loggedInUrl : guestUrl);
    var products = [],
      total = 0;
    $('#my-cart .product').each(function(index, el) {
      total += parseFloat($(el).attr('data-total'));
      products.push({
        'name': $(el).attr('data-title'),
        'sku': $(el).attr('data-sku'),
        'price': $(el).attr('data-price'),
        'quantity': $(el).attr('data-qty')
      });
    });
    return $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: request,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        'items': products,
        'shipping_address': {
          'line1': $scope.streetAddress1,
          'line2': $scope.streetAddress2,
          'city': $scope.city,
          'country_code': KANE.territory,
          'postal_code': $scope.zip,
          'state': $scope.state,
          'phone': '9999999999',
          normalization_status: 'UNKNOWN',
          'status': 'CONFIRMED',
          'type': 'HOME',
          'recipient_name': $scope.firstName,
        },
        'total': KANE.cartObject.grandTotal,
        'currency': 'USD',
        'subtotal': KANE.cartObject.subtotal,
        'tax': '0.00',
        'shipping': parseFloat(templateShippingMethods[$scope.shippingMethod].price).toFixed(2).toString(),
        'shipping_discount': KANE.cartObject.discountAmount,
        'email': ($scope.email) ? $scope.email : '',
        'description': 'This is the payment transaction description.'
      }),
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json"
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.approvalUrl);
      window.location.replace(response.approvalUrl);
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Send Stripe Payment');
    var guestUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/magento/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/order/';
    var loggedInUrl = SOURCE_API + 'source/magento/V1/carts/mine/order/';
    if (KANE.isLoggedIn) {
      return $.ajax({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: loggedInUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "paymentMethod": {
            "method": "md_stripe_cards",
            "additionalData": {
              "md_stripe_card_id": userDataObject.savedPaymentMethods[$scope.paymentMethod].cardId,
              "md_stripe_customer_id": userDataObject.stripeCustId,
              "from_venue": "1"
            }
          },
        }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
      })
    } else {
      return $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: guestUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "paymentMethod": {
            "method": "md_stripe_cards",
            "additionalData": {
              "md_stripe_token": "tok_u5dg20Gra",
              "from_venue": "1"
            }
          }
        }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Side question: Why are you using `$.ajax()` instead of `$http.post()`, and why is this filled with DOM manipulations? I think you're misusing Angular.

Comment: Not my project. Was told to do it this way. That isn't really relevant to the question, if you aren't going to offer help, please don't chime in with your two cents.

Comment: what jQuery-version are you using?

Comment: I would pull the then() calls out into separate functions, so that the function that makes the $.ajax call always returns the direct promise. That should make the logic easier to see in the source code. The functions either create the promise with $.ajax, or, direct flow with then().catch() logic, but not both of these things in the same given function.

Comment: So if then(succes, fail) does not work then are you getting errors in your success callback? It is very messy code, if you could provide smallest possible example of problem you have it would help us understand it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

(pseudo-code)

```
$scope.b_ok = false
$scope.give_up = false

p = a.then(
  while (!$scope.b_ok && !$scope.give_up) {
    p = b.then(c)
  }
)

p.catch(show_error)
```

and in b:

```
return ajax.then(set_b_ok_to_true).catch(tell_them_to_retry)
```

and in tell_them_to_retry you'll want to reject(reason) so that c does not follow b.

Comment: how would an infinite loop help?

Comment: I think my pseudo code is incorrect but I don't have time today to actually try this out in Javascript. But I think you can get the idea of how to brute force this with relatively simple logic.